# Sharing a variable between classes

Tags: java, swing

I have create 2 JFrame in Netbeans(Booking, ConfirmBooking), both there frame are connected to a SQL database. In the Booking class the user chooses a resort form the table displayed by entering a number in a jtextfield. If the user pushes the next button. Class Booking is disposed and ConfirmBooking is opened. I want to access the variable that was entered in Booking in the jtextfield in ConfirmBooking to access the name of the resort the user booked.

Booking Class coding, I want to access the ID that is set to public int above in the class.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String x = jTextFieldID.getText();
    ID = Integer.valueOf(x);
    String sql = "SELECT RESORT_NAME FROM LouwDataBase.Resorts WHERE ID = "+ ID;  
        try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {

                try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery()) {
                    if (rs.next()) {
                    String resortName = rs.getString("RESORT_NAME");

                    int n =  JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
                    "Do you want to make a booking at "+resortName+"?",
                    "Confirm booking?", 
                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, 
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, 
                    null, 
                    new String[]{"Yes I do", "No I don't"},"default");


                    if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) 
                    {
                        ConfirmBooking CB = new ConfirmBooking();
                        dispose();
                        CB.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                        CB.setVisible(true);

                    } 
                        else if (n == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) 
                    {              
            }  
        }
    }

} 
catch (SQLException ex) 
{
Logger.getLogger(Booking.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

}
```

ConfirmBooking Class code

```
    public void SetUp()
    {
        UserList();

        String sql = "SELECT RESORT_NAME, COST_PER_NIGHT_ZAR FROM LouwDataBase.Resorts WHERE ID = "+ ID;  
            try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) 
            {
                    try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery()) 
                    {
                        if (rs.next()) 
                        {
                        String Name1 = rs.getString("RESORT_NAME");
                        double Price = rs.getDouble("COST_PER_NIGHT_ZAR");
                        String Rands = Double.toString(Price);
                        ResortName.setText(Name1);
                        ResortPrice.setText("R "+Rands);
                        }
                    }
            } 
            catch (SQLException ex) 
            {
                Logger.getLogger(Booking.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Can't you inject variables you need into `ConfirmBooking` constructor or something? Are you forbidden from modifying these classes?

Comment: No, this is my school PAT(Practical assessment task) I must create my own program and do research on the programming not learned in class.

Comment: So what exactly stops you from passing variables via constructor or some method?

Comment: I tried to do it, but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could modify a little the ConfirmBooking class so you can pass that variable in the constructor of the class maybe

and then you can do:

```
if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
     ConfirmBooking CB = new ConfirmBooking(ID);
     dispose();
     CB.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
     CB.setVisible(true);
}
```

you store that ID in a member of the `ConfirmBooking`  and retrieve that in the setUp method whenever you need it!

Comment: what do you mean returned? returned to where?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
ConfirmBooking CB = new ConfirmBooking();
CB.setResortNumber(resortName);
```